# Netforum - What does recno stands for

Tags: api, authentication, avectra

For the [Avectra Netforum API](http://www.avectra.com/netforum/netforum-overview.php) service change password call for WEBWebUserChangePassword requires recno as a parameter apart from oldpassword and newpassword, Any clue what does that recno stands for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **recno** property refers to the record ID of the customer. It is an integer that is unique across all customers to an instance of a netFORUM Enterprise (in the database, that column is an identity column).

Generally, a typical flow will go like this: an application will authenticate a user by calling **WEBWebUserLogin**. That method returns an object called a **WebUserType**, in which there is a node called **Customer** which has a property called **cst_recno**. The value of that property is what you will pass to the recno property of WEBWebUserChangePassword.